# Writing sine wave using libpng in c

Tags: c, libpng

Using libpng. I wrote a code (most of it is copy pasted from [How to change rgb values from a png image with libpng using c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185114/how-to-change-rgb-values-from-a-png-image-with-libpng-using-c)). My attempt was to write a png with a waveform, but something is quite wrong here in my puny sine wave:

[image: puny sine wave]

The code to generate this png:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "png.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
//#define _USING_MATH_DEFINES

#define ERROR 1


int width, height;

png_byte color_type;
png_byte bit_depth;
png_bytep *row_pointers;

void read_png_file(char *filename) {
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
  if(!fp) abort();
  png_structp png = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if(!png) abort();
  png_infop info = png_create_info_struct(png);
  if(!info) abort();
  if(setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png))) abort();
  png_init_io(png, fp);
  png_read_info(png, info);
  width      = png_get_image_width(png, info);
  height     = png_get_image_height(png, info);
  color_type = png_get_color_type(png, info);
  bit_depth  = png_get_bit_depth(png, info);
  printf("width: %d height: %d\n", width, height);

  if(bit_depth == 16)
    png_set_strip_16(png);

  if(color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE)
    png_set_palette_to_rgb(png);

  if(color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY && bit_depth < 8)
    png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8(png);

  if(png_get_valid(png, info, PNG_INFO_tRNS))
    png_set_tRNS_to_alpha(png);

  if(color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB ||
     color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY ||
     color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE)
    png_set_filler(png, 0xFF, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);

  if(color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY ||
     color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY_ALPHA)
    png_set_gray_to_rgb(png);

  png_read_update_info(png, info);

  row_pointers = (png_bytep*)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height);
  for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*)malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png,info));
    //printf("%d\n", row_pointers[y]);
  }

  png_read_image(png, row_pointers);

  fclose(fp);
}

void write_png_file(char *filename) {
  int y;

  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
  if(!fp) abort();

  png_structp png = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if (!png) abort();

  png_infop info = png_create_info_struct(png);
  if (!info) abort();

  if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png))) abort();

  png_init_io(png, fp);

  png_set_IHDR(
    png,
    info,
    width, height,
    8,
    PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA,
    PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
    PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT,
    PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT
  );

  png_set_expand(png);
  png_write_info(png, info);
  png_write_image(png, row_pointers);
  png_write_end(png, NULL);

  for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    free(row_pointers[y]);
  }
  free(row_pointers);

  fclose(fp);
}

void process_png_file() {


    const int midY = ceil(height/2);
    printf("midY: %d\n", midY);
    int countY = -midY+height;
    printf("countY: %d\n", countY);
    png_byte color[] = {255,255,255};
    png_byte color_white[] = {0,0,0};
  for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    png_bytep row = row_pointers[y];
    //printf("debug proc\n");

    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      png_bytep px = &(row[x * 4]);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
            if (y == ceil((midY-sin(x*300)))){
                //printf("y: %d ceil: %d\n",y, ceil(sin(x)));
                px[i] = color[i];
            }
            else {
                px[i] = color_white[i];
            }

        }
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if(argc != 3) abort();

  read_png_file(argv[1]);
  process_png_file();

  write_png_file(argv[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

In function process, this is probably where the problem started:

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      png_bytep px = &(row[x * 4]);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
            if (y == ceil((midY-sin(x*300)))){ //this part
                //printf("y: %d ceil: %d\n",y, ceil(sin(x)));
                px[i] = color[i];
            }
            else {
                px[i] = color_white[i];
            }

        }
    }
```

I want it to be much more have a big amplitude.

While I want the code to be much more shorter, it seems that it needs a dummy png like https://github.com/mikolalysenko/lena/blob/master/lena.png that's why the size of the png looks the same. you can though remove the read_png_file() because we're just dealing with the writing stuff (I don't know how to do it that's why it's copy pasta).

Comment: You need to decide on the mapping between pixels and the numbers you're plotting.  Right now you're taking the output of `sin()` and treating it as a pixel count, so 1 pixel == 1 unit.  And then on the horizontal axis you're multiplying `x` by 300, which seems to mean 1 pixel == 300 units == 300 radians.  If you want a sine wave that's (say) 50 pixels high, and where one period of the sine wave takes more like 50 pixels, you want to use something like `50 * sin( x / 50 * PI)`, where of course `PI` is 3.14159.

Comment: @Steve That kind of work https://i.imgur.com/7LDbWUQ.png... But I will be solving the gap problem first. I kinda have an idea why that occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sin` function takes an argument in radians. A complete wave is only 6.28 radians (pi times 2). Since `x` is the number of pixels from the left, you skip over 300 radians for each pixel, which means you actually skip over 47.75 entire waves per pixel, which looks the same as going backwards by 0.25 waves per pixel. Therefore the waves in your image are only 4 pixels wide (per wave).

I suggest trying 0.1 radians per pixel, or so. That will make the waves approximately 62.8 pixels wide, so they're actually big enough to see. Change `sin(x*300)` to `sin(x*0.1)`.

---

The Y values in a sine wave only go between -1 and 1. Since you're using the Y value to figure out which pixel to draw, the waves are only 2 pixels tall. I suggest you multiply this by 50 or so, to make your waves 100 pixels tall, so they're actually big enough to see. Change `sin(whatever)` to `sin(whatever)*50`.

Comment: It has also some quite of gaps, but I'm gonna figure it out. https://imgur.com/4zXOXMA

Comment: Don't forget to play around with those numbes (0.1 and 50) until you like the size of the sine waves.